# How to execute custom SQL query when deleting a model item in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I want to execute an SQL query, when an item gets deleted in the admin interface. In models.py I do this:

```
from django.db import connection

class LList(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, models.DO_NOTHING)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('DELETE FROM some_table where item = %d', [self.item.id])
```

When I turn debugging on I see all the queries executed. It seems the DELETE FROM query is not executed, I only see

```
(0.000) DELETE FROM `llist` WHERE `llist`.`id` IN (27); args=(27,)
```

Why is the other DELETE FROM query not executed? How can I fix that?

Comment: How did you execute the ***delete operation*** in the admin interface?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, didn't know there were 2 possibilities to delete an item. I want the SQL query beeing executed in both possible ways, with delete selected and delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the delete function the wrong way,

```
def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('''DELETE FROM some_table where item = %d''', [self.item.id])

    super(LList, self).delete(using, keep_parents)
```

But I believe the better way would be to do it using signals, you should create a pre_delete signal.

Comment: Great, this way the direct delete works, but when I delete the item via delete selected it does not work. What kind of function do I have to call in this case?

Comment: Can you please write down the sql query that you are trying to execute. I will be better able to solve the problem then.